# How to get URL of current WebView?

Tags: android, url, webview, android-sharing

I am developing an app where the user sees a WebView. There is a share FloatingActionButton to share the link to Facebook or Whatsapp.

I am using a Navigation Drawer Activity. 
Both the WebView and the FAB are in the `content_main.xml`
On selecting each option in the drawer the WebView loads accordingly.

So to get the URL i used `webView.getUrl()` method. But on running the app whenever I touch the share FAB the app force closes. Without that method I am able to proceed further but I have no url.

My code is:

```
WebView mywebView;
FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            String url;
            //url=myWebView.getOriginalUrl().toString();
            url=myWebView.getUrl().toString();
            String message = "Text I want to share.";
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");


            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));

        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to extract the code from the anonymous listener class to a method and call the method instead. Second, always check for Null Pointer before you call any method . And third, no need to call myWebView.getUrl().toString(), it is useless like calling string.toString().

```
private WebView myWebView = super.findViewById(R.id.mywebViewId);

private void setFabListener() {

    FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) super.findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             doOnFabPressed();
        }
    });

}

private void doOnFabPressed() {

    if (this.myWebView != null) {

        String url = this.myWebView.getUrl();
        String message = "Text I want to share.";

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);

        super.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));

    }


}
```